# Random sequence of colors

Tags: java

How to chose **only** one picture which can't repeat?

I tried this:

I use random and i want to delete selected picture

```
String[] picture = { "blue", "white", "red", "yellow" };

   int number_picture1; 

// Random function to find a random picture

   Random ran = new Random();

   number_picture1 = ran.nextInt(picture.length);

System.out.println(picture[number_picture1]);

// There is still posibility to chose the same picture

   int number_picture2; 

   number_picture2 = ran.nextInt(picture.length);

System.out.println(picture[number_picture2]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest way is to use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)<sup>1</sup> to store your elements, and use [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) on it - and then take elements iteratively.

The shuffle produces a random permutation of the list, so chosing items iteratively gives you the same probability to chose any ordering, which seems to be exactly what you are after.

Code snap:

```
String[] picture = { "blue", "white", "red", "yellow" };
//get a list out of your array:
List<String> picturesList = Arrays.asList(picture);
//shuffle the list:
Collections.shuffle(picturesList);
//first picture is the first element in list:
String pictureOne = picturesList.get(0);
System.out.println(pictureOne);
//2nd picture is the 2nd element in list:
String pictureTwo = picturesList.get(1);
System.out.println(pictureTwo);
...
```

---

(1) Simplest way to get the list from an array is using [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Comment: @LukaToni Don't use `java.awt.List`, you need to use [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). See the documentation for this interface.

Answer (score 3):

Using a Collection is a much better option in retrieving and deleting. With Arrays, keep a track of the indices which has already been selected. Also, if the number of selections is greater than the the length of the array, just throw an exception accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `List` or `Set` instead of an array, then remove the selected picture from it after each selection:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

List<String> pictures = Arrays.asList("blue","white","red","yellow");
int number_picture1;

number_picture1=ran.nextInt(pictures.size());
System.out.println (pictures.remove(number_picture1));

int number_picture2;

number_picture2=ran.nextInt(pictures.size());
...
```

Comment: @LukaToni no offence, but if you must ask that I'd like to advise you to read some basic Java book first. Again, no offence meant.

Answer (score 1):

Although you haven't given the declaration of `ran`, I guess it's the standard JDK random number generator.

That one has no guarantee whatsoever that not the same number is selected twice. In a true random algorithm that would be a rather strange guarantee.

One way to solve this is to put the numbers corresponding to your choices in a linked list (here {0,1,2,3}). Then pick a random integer between 0 and the size of your list (3 here). Say you get '2', then remove the second element from the list making it thus {0,1,3}. Next time pick a number between 0 and 2. If you now get a '2' again, you again remove the second element which is now '3'. Etc.